# Method to locate Twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig, full-text-search

I often do front-end on Symfony projects, and when it's something I took over from someone else, I often can't determine which Twig template I need to edit. So I usually either do a full-text search in `views` directories, or I harass fellow back-ender.

But is there any universal method in Symfony for this? Like in Magento, where you can turn on dev module which prints template paths above content in browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're working with development environment you should have Symfony's Profiler Toolbar available on the bottom of page.

On the left there's current route name - something like `@homepage` (starts with `@`). When you hover on it, you'll see something like this:

[image]

Now, when you'll go into `DefaultController::indexAction()` source, you'll see, what template is being rendered in this view.

You can also open the profiler by clicking on it. There's a Twig tab where you can find detailed information about what templates has been rendered.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you are on your web page, you can check the symfony dev toolbar, where you can find which controller and action is called.

You just have to look in this action which template is call and you got the right twig template